# Como criar um csv a partir de uma consulta do banco e dados

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Consegui criar um arquivo .xls perfeito, mas o .csv não consigo, segue o código que usei para criar o .xls

```
$dadosXls  = "";
    $dadosXls .= "  <table border='1' >";
    $dadosXls .= "          <tr>";
    $dadosXls .= "          <th>Nr-Série</th>";
    $dadosXls .= "          <th>Cód-Secret</th>";
    $dadosXls .= "          <th>QtdPontos</th>";
    $dadosXls .= "          <th>DataImpres</th>";
    $dadosXls .= "          <th>Id-Estab</th>";
    $dadosXls .= "          <th>Status</th>";
    $dadosXls .= "          <th>DtaValidadeReg</th>";
    $dadosXls .= "          <th>DataImportacao</th>";
    $dadosXls .= "          <th>IdRegra</th>";
    $dadosXls .= "      </tr>";



    while ($escrever=mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
        $dadosXls .= "      <tr>";
        $dadosXls .= "          <td>".$escrever['nrSerie']."</td>";
        $dadosXls .= "          <td>".$escrever['codSecreto']."</td>";
        $dadosXls .= "          <td>".$escrever['QtdPontos']."</td>";
        $dadosXls .= "          <td>".$escrever['DataImpres']."</td>";
        $dadosXls .= "          <td></td>";
        $dadosXls .= "          <td>".$escrever['Status']."</td>";
        $dadosXls .= "          <td>".$escrever['DtaValidadeReg']."</td>";
        $dadosXls .= "          <td>".$escrever['DataImportacao']."</td>";
        $dadosXls .= "          <td>680</td>";
        $dadosXls .= "      </tr>";
    }
    $dadosXls .= "  </table>";
```

agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Sugiro que leia [ask] e [mcve](/help/mcve) para saber como fazer uma boa pergunta. E sinceramente não entendi o que você quer, exportar csv do banco ou do php?

Comment: de uma olhada no http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/, uma lib muito boa para importar e exportar dados, antigamente eu fazia da mesma forma que vc esta fazendo, depois que conheci essa lib minha vida mudou para melhor... ;)

Comment: Diego, faço uma query com php e com o resultado dessa querie quero fazer um arquivo .csv

Comment: Marcelo, obrigado pela sugestão, mas não entendi muito bem como funciona esse framework.

Answer (score 5):

Csv é um arquivo com os valores separados por virgulas, pode criar um combinando [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) para transformar o array(`$escrever`) em uma string delimitada por virgulas e usar [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) para escrever o arquivo. Outra opção de saída é formatar o cabeçalho como csv para o navegador e dar um echo na string.

Criar um arquivo:

```
$str = "";
while ($escrever = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
    $str .= implode(',', $escrever) .','. PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents('dados.csv', $str);
```

Download do csv:

```
$str = "";
while ($escrever = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
    $str .= implode(',', $escrever) .','. PHP_EOL;
}

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=dados.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo $str;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Tentei fazer, mas no arquivo ele escreve duas vezes o mesmo valor.

Comment: @MuriloSouza, editei a resposta, você precisa trocar o `mysqli_fetch_array()` pelo `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, a primera função retorna a mesma informação duas vezes uma com indices números e outra com indices associativos.

Comment: @MuriloSouza funcionou?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um código parecido. Basta você remover as tags referentes a tabela e substituir por , (vírgula). Lembre que no  final de cada linha deve haver um "\n"

```
<?php
    // cabeçalho do csv
    // muitas pessoas gostam de importar csv. e quando fazem isso, gostam
    // de que o nome de cada coluna, para que elas saibam que tipo de informação
    // há ali
    $dadosCsv  = "";
    $dadosCsv .= "Nr-Série,";
    $dadosCsv .= "Cód-Secret,";
    $dadosCsv .= "QtdPontos,";
    $dadosCsv .= "DataImpres,";
    $dadosCsv .= "Id-Estab,";
    $dadosCsv .= "Status,";
    $dadosCsv .= "DtaValidadeReg,";
    $dadosCsv .= "DataImportacao,";
    $dadosCsv .= "IdRegra\n";

    while ($escrever = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
        // devemos colocar as strings entre aspas. e um addslashes ajuda 
        // evitar conflitos entre elas
        // as aspas entre colunas também ajuda caso o texto contenha uma virgula
        $dadosCsv .= '"'. addslashes($escrever['nrSerie']).'",';
        $dadosCsv .= '"'.addslashes($escrever['codSecreto']).'",';
        $dadosCsv .= "".addslashes($escrever['QtdPontos']).'",';
        $dadosCsv .= "".addslashes($escrever['DataImpres']).'",';
        $dadosCsv .= '"",';
        $dadosCsv .= '"'.addslashes($escrever['Status']).'",';
        $dadosCsv .= '"'.addslashes($escrever['DtaValidadeReg']).'",';
        $dadosCsv .= '"'.addslashes($escrever['DataImportacao']).'",';
        $dadosCsv .= "680,";
        $dadosCsv .= "\n";
    }

    // exemplo para download do arquivo .csv
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=dados.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    echo $dadosCsv;
    // fim do arquivo .php
```

Se algum texto ficar com um "encoding" errado no seu arquivo (por exemplo "CÃ³d-Secret") use `utf8_encode`

```
// ...
$dadosCsv .= utf8_encode("Nr-Série,");
// ...
$dadosCsv .= '"'.addslashes(utf8_encode($escrever['Status'])).'",';
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Funcionou em partes o Nr-Série e o Cód-Secret fom escritos assim Nr-SÃ©rie,CÃ³d-Secret e também escreveu as tags html <html><body> no arquivo, como faço pra resolver esses prolbemas?

Comment: vou editar a resposta e mostrar como o arquivo deverá ficar.

Comment: tente fazer com que não tenha nenhum código html antes do início "<?php". Quando tiver um tempo, procure sobre templates e mvc. Também faça uma pesquisa sobre PDO (um objeto para trabalhar melhor com banco de dados)